# An intriguing integral $\int \ln{|\nabla u|^2}\, \mathrm{d}u$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate

$\int \ln{|\nabla u|^2}\, \mathrm{d}u$ ?

In Cartesian co-ordinates this would be $\int \ln{(u_x^2 + u_y^2)}\, \mathrm{d}u$, where $u_x \equiv \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$. We know $\nabla^2 u = 0$, but nothing more. $u$ is a two-dimensional real-valued field; in Cartesians $u = u(x,y)$.

I do not have any idea how to treat the $x$ and $y$. I guess one could try $\mathrm{d}u = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}y$, but this seems to only make it worse. Is this kind of an integral even well defined?

Is the 'easier' integral (where we know $\nabla^2 u = 0$)

$\int |\nabla u|^2\, \mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{2} \int \nabla^2 u^2\, \mathrm{d}u$

different or doable?

We can write this as $\int |\nabla u|^2\, \nabla u \cdot \mathrm{d} \textbf{r}$. Then the question is equivalently how to find $\phi$ such that $\nabla \phi = \nabla^2 u^2 \nabla u$, for use in the gradient theorem to reduce the integral to a boundary term.

Comment: $u$ depends on $x$ and $y$. What dou you mean by $du$?

Comment: In the same fashion as  $\cos{(x)}\,\,\mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{d}\left[\sin{(x)} \right] \equiv  \mathrm{d}u$, where $u = \sin{(x)}$. For example $ \sin{(x)} \cos{(x)}\,\,\mathrm{d}x =  \sin{(x)} \mathrm{d}\left[\sin{(x)} \right] \equiv u \mathrm{d}u$. $u$ depends on $x$ and $y$ only in the Cartesian co-ordinate representation; I believe vectors are more abstract than a specific representation and the particular components in that system.

Comment: Is it formally allowed to change the order of differentiation and integration above? In that case we can write 

$\frac{1}{2} \int \nabla^2 u^2\, \mathrm{d}u =\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2  \int u^2\, \mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{6}\nabla^2 u^3 = \frac{1}{2}u\nabla^2 u^2$. Differentiating this w.r.t $u$ gives back the integrand: $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u} \left( \frac{1}{2}u\nabla^2 u^2\right) = \frac{1}{2} \nabla^2 u^2 + u \nabla^2 u = \frac{1}{2} \nabla^2 u^2$.

Comment: A few questions. First, it's probably not $du$ but $dS=dx\,dy$. Secondly, write the last one as $\int |\nabla u|^2 dS=-\int u\nabla^2 u dS+\text{boundary term}$ (Green's theorem, or integration by parts, or whatever you call it).

Comment: Then my question is really what is the integration domain here? It doesn't make sense in this form! If $u$ depends on $x$ and $y$, then, do you integrate the expression on some curve? Or at a point? I really wonder how you can justify this.

Comment: To answer your questions, we can write the integral as $\int \ln{|\nabla u|^2}\, \nabla u \cdot \mathrm{d} \textbf{r}$, and the easier one as $\int |\nabla u|^2\, \nabla u \cdot \mathrm{d} \textbf{r}$. How to evaluate this? We  know $\nabla^2 u = 0$.

Comment: Equivalently, my question is how to find $\phi$ such that $\nabla \phi = \nabla^2 u^2 \nabla u$. Then one can use the gradient theorem to reduce the integral to a boundary term, which would be enough for me.